# Resolution of FRR Function

Tags: oscilloscope, pulse, phase-shift

I am working with a oscilloscope GWINSTEK gds-2074a. As per the time resolution is concerned, turning the dial all the way down, it shows that it can go down to 1 ns.  There is a Delay function in the oscilloscope and I have to use the FRR function. Can any one guide how I can find its resolution? The pulses which I want to study is expected to have a time difference of 2 ns. I checked the manuals and could not find it anywhere. Any resource in this matter or guidance would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To see down to a resoution of 1nS, you would need 1/f = t or 1GHz scope.

The scope you has a bandwidth of 70MHz or 1/f = t or 14.2ns

[image]

If you really want to see 2ns (500Mhz) then you'll need double or a 1GHz scope to really see what is going on. Impedance and inductance will become an issue with measurement rise times, so make sure you use proper technique when making this kind of measurement.

For more info [see this](https://community.keysight.com/community/keysight-blogs/oscilloscopes/blog/2018/02/28/what-is-oscilloscope-sample-rate-and-how-much-do-you-need)

Comment: Thanks for the info. The FRR function in Delay gives the time difference between the rise time of two pulses. In this case both the pulses are square. Do you know if the time resolution of that function in oscilloscope would also be about 14 ns?